# Bringing EditText to front of WebView Android

Tags: java, android, webview

I have the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    EditText userfield;
    EditText passfield;
    Button logbtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userfield = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        passfield = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        logbtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);

        GifWebView view = new GifWebView(this, "file:///android_asset/watg.gif");

        view.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        view.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

        setContentView(view);

        userfield.bringToFront();
        userfield.invalidate();
        passfield.bringToFront();
        passfield.invalidate();
        logbtn.bringToFront();
        logbtn.invalidate();

    }
```

As you can see the GifWebView (extends WebView) is created programatically after the onCreate()

The button and EditTexts are made in the Activity.xml but are brought to front programatically in the Java file.

Why doesnt the above code work?

**EDIT - Frame Layout Problem**

My XML Code

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <com.example.dencallanan.giftestapp.GifWebView android:id="@+id/GWebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        />

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_marginBottom="153dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:hint="USERNAME" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/editText"
            android:hint="PASSWORD" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Log In"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>


</FrameLayout>
```

The Error:

[image]

Comment: Can you share your XML file? If not I suggest you to use a RelativeLayout or a FrameLayout. Why? Because those Layouts support "Stackable views".

Comment: You are calling setContentView 2 times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)` and again later `setContentView(view)`. `setContentView` will overwrite the layout, this will in effect, replace it with a new layout. I suggest using a `FrameLayout in XML` file... `Webview` will be your bottom layer. On top of that Put a `Linear/RelativeLayout` with the `Edittexts` and `Button`... Simple and clean.

You can add your webview in XML like:

```
<com.package.GifWebView android:id="@+id/GWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
/>
```

In code, access this as:

```
GifWebView gWView = (GifWebView) findViewById(R.id.GWebView);
gWView = new GifWebView(this, "file:///android_asset/watg.gif");
```

Comment: Makes sense. But my webView is not created inside the xml file. So how would I do this. Notice I am using GifWebView, not WebView

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I will EDIT my answer to show you the problem I am having with Frame Layout

Comment: hi, i need to see your GifWebView class contents... then i can test.. BTW, u can unaccept the answer for now as this question is unanswered still.. :-)

Comment: I have made some progress/changes. See here for all code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31045159/extending-a-custom-layout-class-constructor-never-used